# Laravel 7 - What could cause intermittent 419 errors?

Tags: laravel, memcached, csrf

I have a website running with Laravel 7 in 3 app servers connected to 1 database server.

The 3 app servers have memcached installed. The session driver is memcached. And I've added the 3 servers in the Laravel configuration for memcached.

config/cache.php

```
...
'memcached' => [
    'driver'  => 'memcached',
    'persistent_id' => 'memcached_pool_id',
    'options' => [
        // some nicer default options
        // - nicer TCP options
        Memcached::OPT_TCP_NODELAY => TRUE,
        Memcached::OPT_NO_BLOCK => FALSE,
        // - timeouts
        Memcached::OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT => 2000,    // ms
        Memcached::OPT_POLL_TIMEOUT => 2000,       // ms
        Memcached::OPT_RECV_TIMEOUT => 750 * 1000, // us
        Memcached::OPT_SEND_TIMEOUT => 750 * 1000, // us
        // - better failover
        Memcached::OPT_DISTRIBUTION => Memcached::DISTRIBUTION_CONSISTENT,
        Memcached::OPT_LIBKETAMA_COMPATIBLE => TRUE,
        Memcached::OPT_RETRY_TIMEOUT => 2,
        Memcached::OPT_SERVER_FAILURE_LIMIT => 1,
        Memcached::OPT_AUTO_EJECT_HOSTS => TRUE,
    ],
    'servers' => [
        [
            'host' => 'ip1',
            'port' => '11211',
            'weight' => 100,
        ],
        [
            'host' => 'ip2',
            'port' => '11211',
            'weight' => 100,
        ],
        [
            'host' => 'ip3',
            'port' => '11211',
            'weight' => 100,
        ]
    ]
]
```

The VerifyCsrfToken middleware is active, and most of the time everything works, but there are some requests that throw a 419 error (randomly), even though they send the appropriate cookies (laravel session and csrf token), and the memcached store has the session data.

When the error occurs, there might've been successful requests before or after the failure.

Is there anything else that could be causing this issue?

Comment: So each app servers has its own memcached installed in them? I think that's why its throwing error 419. you have to have only single point of contact of storing the sessions. You can use the `database` as session driver

Comment: Actually, memcached is supposed to work like this, if the connection is made to all 3 servers, the data gets distributed and it's like a cluster. But I will try to setup a separate server with redis, and use that as the session store.